# If the sum and the product of two sets are equal are the sets?

Tags: abstract-algebra

I have the following lemma that I can't seem to disprove or prove but which I am assuming someone here will make short work of.  I will first write a simple case and then a more general case.

Simple case:

Let $\mathbb{F}_q$ be a finite field of prime order $q$.

$\forall a, b, c, d \in \mathbb{F}_q$ where $a$ and $b$ are non zero

if $a + b = c + d$ and $a*b=c*d$

then $(a=c \land b=d) \lor (a=d \land b=c)$

General case:

Let $\mathbb{F}_q^n$ be a vector space of dimension $n$ over a finite field of prime order $q$.

$\forall a,b \in \mathbb{F}_q^n$, where all elements in $a$ are non zero

if $\sum_{i=1}^n a_i = \sum_{i=1}^n b_i$ and $\prod_{i=1}^n a_i = \prod_{i=1}^n b_i$

then there exists a permutation matrix $M$ such that $aM=b$.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Little tip [irrelevant to the question]: the tags should be correct. So i assume it should be "abstract-algebra"

Comment: The first one is true.  Write $a+b=x=c+d,$ then substitute $b=x-a,d=x-c$ into $ab=cd,$ and forge ahead.

Comment: The title asks "does $a+b=ab$ imply $a=b$. But the body asks whether a set is determined by its sum and its product.

Comment: If $\mathbb F$ is an $m$-element field, then there are $\binom{m-1}3$ sets $\{a_1,a_2,a_3\}$ of three distinct nonzero elements, while there are only $m(m-1)$ possible pairs $(a_1+a_2+a_3,a_1a_2a_3)$.

Comment: @bof the question in the body is what I meant.  I didn't now how to concisely phrase it in the title.  I mean $n$ elements from $\mathbb{F}_q$

Comment: In $\mathbb F_{11}$, $1+4+8+9=2+3+7+10$ and $1\cdot4\cdot8\cdot9=2\cdot3\cdot7\cdot10$.

Comment: "Are $n$ nonzero numbers determined by their sum and product?" It doesn't seem too likely that $n$ numbers could be determined by only $2$, does it?

Comment: In $\mathbb F_{11}$, $1+9+10=2+3+4$ and $1\cdot9\cdot10=2\cdot3\cdot4$.

Comment: The question has now been answered in the comments. Could @saulspatz or bof write it up as a real answer to get the question off the unanswered list?

Comment: @bof, please see my comment above (for some stupid reason it is not possible to notify two users in the same comment)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's true for two elements in any field.  We have $a+b=x=c+d,$ so
$b=x-a,\ d=x-c.$  Then $$ab=cd \iff a(x-a)=c(x-c)\iff x(a-c)=(a-c)(a+c)$$  Either $a-c = 0,$ and then $b=d,$ or $$x=a+c\iff a+b=a+c\iff b=c.$$

As @bof has indicated in a comment, the statement is false for $n>2.$